# Equation with one variable unknow how to solve easily

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have

$$\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
x & -2 & 3x-6 \\
2x & \phantom{-}0 & 2-x \\
-x & \phantom{-}5 & x-2 
\end{array}\right| = 0$$

How can I solve this with a fast way? I thought I can do 
$$x-2+3x-6=0 \implies 4x=-8 \implies x=-2$$ 
and I will continue with the other two, but I don't know if I am right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elements of the first column are all multiples of $x$; elements in the third column are all multiples of $x-2$. You can factor the determinant thusly:

$$0 = \left|\begin{array}{ccc}
\phantom{-}x & -2 & 3x-6 \\
2x & \phantom{-}0 & 2-x \\
-x & \phantom{-}5 & x-2 
\end{array}\right| = 
x(x-2) \left|\begin{array}{ccc}
\phantom{-}1 & -2 & \phantom{-}3 \\
\phantom{-}2& \phantom{-}0 & -1 \\
-1& \phantom{-}5 & \phantom{-}1 
\end{array}\right| =
37x(x-2) \quad\implies\quad x=0,2$$

---

To add a bit of detail ...

Determinant rules allow you to factor-out common multipliers from an individual colunmn (or row):

$$\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
pa & b & c \\
pd & e & f \\
ph & i & j
\end{array}\right| \;=\; p\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
h & i & j
\end{array}\right|$$

The justification is immediately clear if you're familiar with the relationship between a determinant and the volume of the parallelepiped determined by the column vectors. But it also makes sense if you pay attention to how determinants are expanded. Here's a quick example with a $2\times 2$:

$$\left|\begin{array}{cc} pa & b \\ pc & d \end{array}\right| = pa\cdot d -pc\cdot b = p(ad-cb) = p\left|\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array}\right|$$ 
Every term in the expansion includes the multiplier, which can be factored-out.

Anyway ... For the problem in question, I factored-out $x$ and $x-2$ from the first and third columns. Then I calculated the value of the remaining determinant (just to make sure it wasn't zero, in which case $x$ could be *anything*).

Comment: can you explain please   how you find 37x(x-2)?

Comment: The first sentence he wrote literally explains what he did. In my opinion this is by far the best and fastest way of doing it.

Comment: http://www.coolmath.com/algebra/14-determinants-cramers-rule/02-determinants-3x3-method-1-03 does this way is useful?  For solve?

Comment: @blue I find 3x3 but not with x inside. If I work as on the link I said will it work?

Comment: @m.s: The link shows how to expand a $3\times 3$ determinant, so it's helpful. If you use it on the original determinant in the problem, you could find yourself multiplying-out a bunch of terms that you'll then have to factor. My solution saves a lot of that effort by factoring-out common multipliers *first*. (This isn't always possible. It just so happens that the problem allows for it.) To get that the remaining numbers-only determinant has value $37$, use the technique described in that CoolMath link.

Comment: I did it . x (x-2)+2x (2-x)+10x (3x-6)-x (3x-6)-5x (2-x)+4x (x-2) that after doing is x (x-2 )+x (2-x) +9x (3x-6) . So it is x (x-2) -x (x-2) +9x (3x-6)  so  0 + 9x (3x-6 ) that is 27x-54 =0 so 27x=54 that is x =54/27 so x =2 . Am I right ?@Blue

Comment: Be mindful of the zeros! Multiplying it out should give you $$\begin{align}\phantom{-}(x)(0)(x-2)+(-2)(2-x)(-x)+(3x-6)(2x)(5)\\-(-x)(0)(3x-6)-(5)(2-x)(x)-(x-2)(2x)(-2)\end{align}$$ Those zero terms go away, so we just have (with minor simplification) $$2x(2-x)+10x(3x-6)-5x(2-x)+4x(x-2)$$ You can multiply out all that mess and combine terms, or you can realize that the terms have common factors $x$ and $x-2$: $$2x\cdot(-1)(x-2)+10x\cdot(3)(x-2)-5x\cdot(-1)(x-2)+4x\cdot(1)(x-2)$$ so you can factor-out to get $$x(x-2)\left(-2+30+5+4\right) = 37 x(x-2)$$ Therefore, $x=0$ and $x=2$ are solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot man :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong: 
$$x-2+3x-6=0 \implies 4x=-8 \implies x=-2 $$

---

This is the right way to do it 
$$\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
x & -2 & 3x-6 \\
2x & \phantom{-}0 & 2-x \\
-x & \phantom{-}5 & x-2 
\end{array}\right| = 0$$

Apply $R3 \rightarrow R3+R1$
$$\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
x & -2 & 3x-6 \\
2x & \phantom{-}0 & 2-x \\
0 & \phantom{-}3 & 4x-8 
\end{array}\right| = 0$$

Apply $R2\rightarrow R2-2R1$
$$\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
x & -2 & 3x-6 \\
0 & \phantom{-}4 & 14-7x \\
0 & \phantom{-}3 & 4x-8 
\end{array}\right| = 0$$

$$x\left(  4(4x-8)-3(14-7x)\right)=0$$
$$37x(x-2)=0 \implies x=0,2$$

Comment: yes sorry.But is the right way this?

Comment: I can't understand what you are asking  can you edit your question using mathjax

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/qCgZxLj   . this is what i ask

Comment: no , i cant get it ,where you going it.If you could continue i would be greatful

Comment: see the updated naswer

Comment: where you find 37x? you mean 3*7x?

Comment: also,if i have similar exercise i work again like this?

Comment: x(16x-32-42+21x)=0 it makes x(37x-74) @Deepesh Meena

Comment: yes then take 37 common it makes $x\cdot 37(x-2)$

yes you can always use this technique

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [Laplace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) on the second column and get

$$\begin{vmatrix}
x & -2 & 3x-6 \\
2x & 0 & 2-x \\
-x & 5 & x-2 
\end{vmatrix} = 2 \begin{vmatrix} 2x & 2-x \\ -x & x-2 \end{vmatrix} - 5 \begin{vmatrix} x & 3x-6 \\ 2x & 2-x \end{vmatrix}=37x(x-2) $$

Hence $x \in \{0,2\}$.